# VHDL program for JK Flip Flop using Case Statement

Tags: syntax, vhdl, ghdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee. std_logic_1164.all;
 entity JKFF is
PORT( j,k,clock: in std_logic;
q,qbar: out std_logic);
end JKFF;
Architecture behavioral of JKFF is
signal jk : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal temp : std logic;
begin

process(clock,j,r)

begin
jk <= j & k;
if(clock= '1' and clock'event) then
 case (jk) is
   when "00" => temp<= temp;
   when "01" => temp <= '0';
   when "10" => temp <= '1';
   when "11" => not temp;
   when others => temp <= 'X'
end case;
end process;
q <= temp;
qbar <= not temp;

end behavioral;
```

When I compiled this program using ghdl it is showing error  'when' is expected instead of 'not'. Please help me to find the problem with this code.

Comment: You could benefit from taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Ask a specific programming question. You have numerous [syntax errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4j3K.jpg). (Google *BNF VHDL*). Consider picking an indentation pattern you like making it easy to notice errors. Proof read. Complete error messages can be helpful to your readers who may have the same issue in the future. (Questions and answers are search resources.)

Comment: (And to be clear `process(clock,j,r)` the `r` in the sensitivity list is a semantic error, it's not a declared signal.)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot these things:

1)`when "11" => not temp;` to `when "11" => temp <= not temp;`

2)`when others => temp <= 'X'` must have semicolon at the end `when others => temp <='X';`

3)you missed `end if`at the end of the if

4)process sensitivity list contains a signal named ‘r’ which is undeclared

I’ve left out the signal j and k from the process because all the code you execute in the if statement is conditioned only by the clock, so there is no need to execute the process when j and k change their value and the clock isn’t on rising edge.

```
library ieee;
use ieee. std_logic_1164.all;
 entity JKFF is
PORT( j,k,clock: in std_logic;
q,qbar: out std_logic);
end JKFF;
Architecture behavioral of JKFF is
signal jk : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal temp : std logic;
begin

process(clock)

begin
jk <= j & k;
if(clock= '1' and clock'event) then
   case (jk) is
     when "00" => temp<= temp;
     when "01" => temp <= '0';
     when "10" => temp <= '1';
     when "11" => temp <= not temp;
     when others => temp <= 'X';
    end case;
end if;
end process;
q <= temp;
qbar <= not temp;

end behavioral;
```

Comment: You missed something. The process sensitivity list contains `r` which is not a declared signal name. IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.2 Wait statement *...Each signal name in the sensitivity list shall be a static signal name, and each name shall denote a signal for which reading is permitted....* Shall has a mandatory weight, see 1.3.1.

Comment: `jk <= j & k;` should be _outside_ of the process statement. Or it should be a process local variable. But I think `case (j&k) is` should just work.

Comment: Actually (j & k) is ambiguous for revisions earlier than -2008. The concatenation operator can either have a return value that's a std_logic_vector or a std_ulogic_vector (in -2008 std_logic_vector is a subtype of std_ulogic_vector and it isn't ambiguous).